# BufferedStream - an attempt was made to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file

Tags: c#, file, exception, io, .net-4.6

I am opening a pretty small file (approx 200 kb) and then I am opening it in a BufferedStream because I am going to be reading it many times.  When I try to create the BufferedStream I get an IOException:

```
var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, true);
using (var bfs = new BufferedStream(stream)); // IOException: An attempt was made to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file.
```

What could be causing the IO Exception?  My app is using .NET 4.6

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't specifically answer your question, but you don't need use a `BufferedStream`. Buffering is already woven into `FileStream`.

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brada/2004/04/15/filestream-and-bufferedstream/

In particular, the following quote stands out:

> Answer (from Brian Grunkemeyer, dev for the System.IO namespace):
>
> No, there is zero benefit from wrapping a BufferedStream around a FileStream.  We copied BufferedStream’s buffering logic into FileStream about 4 years ago to encourage better default performance (Pit of Success).  In fact, I don’t think there are any Streams in the .NET Framework that require it, but it might be needed by custom Stream implementations if they do not do buffering by default.